# sorting array by frequent letter repeating

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I was thinking about what could be the best way to sort array by same letters count in one element. For example I have an array with these elements:

```
barorry [which has 3 r letters]
nathan [which has 2 a letters]
ananas [which has 3 a letters]
```

and then sort those elements in order from highest to lowest which would result

```
barorry [which has 3 r letters]
ananas [which has 3 a letters]
nathan [which has 2 a letters]
```

I've been thinking about this for the last hour and I still can't get my head around it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Some more information would be helpful.  For example, what have you tried besides thinking about it? :)  Also, should a word appear more than once on the list?  For example, how should the word "aaabccc" be sorted? Should it appear twice?  [Here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about posting questions here to ensure the best results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = ['barorry ', 'nathan', 'ananas '];
$tempArr = [];

foreach($myArray as $key => $s)
   $tempArr[$key] = max(count_chars($s));
arsort($tempArr);

foreach($tempArr as $key => $value)
    $res[] = $myArray[$key];

    print_r($res); // Array ( [0] => barorry [1] => ananas [2] => nathan )
```

This does what your asked in your question. I tried to keep it very simple. 
        A better solution would be to make a deeper comparaison if two words has
            same number of characters.